# Best Way of Adding Product to Wishlist

Tags: url, redirect, wishlist

I have an option inside the cart to add a product to the wishlist which works fine.

```
   onclick="jQuery.get('<?php echo $this->getUrl('myaccount/checkout/wishlist') ?>', { product: <?php echo $_item->getProductId() ?> }).done(function(data) { location.reload(true); });
```

But if you are not logged in you are first taken to a log in page. After this I set up a redirect using the same url that is submitted from the cart to add a product to you wishlist.

```
   https://temperley.localhost/shop/myaccount/checkout/wishlist/product:25192
```

Problem is this url does not work in this situation. I've tried using http instead of https and vice versa which isn't working. I would appreciate if anyone could describe how exactly I can add a product to the wishlist from a redirect off the login page or add a product by id to the wishlist

Comment: Is this a custom module as url for the wish list should look like: `/wishlist/index/add/product/167/` or `/wishlist/index/fromcart/item/93/` from the cart

Answer (score 1):

Magento adds the parameter with `/` to the url, therefore the url must be

```
https://temperley.localhost/shop/myaccount/checkout/wishlist/product/25192
```

or (the classic way)

```
https://temperley.localhost/shop/myaccount/checkout/wishlist/?product=25192
```

Comment: I've tried using urls like that but it didn't work. Also when you are logged in the url in the format that I have used worked

Comment: Interessting, it should work. You know, that everything is handled here: `\Mage_Wishlist_IndexController::addAction`. So the only suggestion I can give you is: Use xdebug, hook into the action method and check what happens.